# passing a date to a function in python that is calling sql server

Tags: python, sql-server, datetime, pandas, pyodbc

I am trying to pass date1 and date 2 to a function in python that creates a dataframe from a sql server

```
  import datetime as dt
  import pandas as pd
  import pyodbc
  import sqlalchemy
  from pandas import Series,DataFrame
  cnx=sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://Omnius:MainBrain1@172.31.163.135:1433/Basis?driver=/opt/microsoft/sqlncli/lib64/libsqlncli-11.0.so.1790.0")

def func1(date1,date2):
sqlquery = "select top 10000 * from Pretty_Txns where Pay_Date between '"+date1+"' and '"+date2+"'"
df=pd.read_sql(sqlquery,cnx)
```

When I try and call this function from ipython

```
  func1(dt.date(2015,05,01),dt.date(2015,05,02))

  ----> 8     sqlquery = "select top 10000 * from Pretty_Txns where Pay_Date between  '"+date1+"' and '"+date2+"'"

 TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'datetime.date' objects
```

How should I call the function so that I dont get the type error.

Comment: generally speaking, you don't quote placeholders. `between ? and ?` are two placeholders, while `between '?' and '?'` are two STRINGS that happen to contain question marks.

Comment: @Bhargav  This question is not an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started.  Your SQL will likely not work unless the date formats match. Print out the sqlquery and test in CLI.

Example conversion:

```
t = datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 23, 0, 0)
t.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')


def func1(date1,date2):
      strDate1 =  date1.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
      strDate2 =  date2.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

      sql = "select top 10000 * from Pretty_Txns where Pay_Date > '%s' and Pay_Date < '%s'  " %    (strDate1, strDate2)
      return sql

sqlquery = func1( DateOne,DateTwo )
#print sqlquery. 

df=pd.read_sql(sqlquery,cnx)
```

Comment: that worked partially..getting below error:

      DataError: (pyodbc.DataError) ('22018', '[22018] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int (206) (SQLExecDirectW)') [SQL: 'select top 10000 * from Pretty_Txns where Pay_Date > 05/01/2015 and Pay_Date < 05/02/2015']

SQL syntax for date is '2015-05-01',

Comment: '%m/%d/%Y' >> %Y-%m-%d  Check the docs! https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: SQL datetime literals needs to be enclosed in single quotes i.e. `Pay_Date > '%s' and Pay_Date < '%s'`

Comment: Mixing SQL and string substitution is a [bad idea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), use [parameters](https://mkleehammer.github.io/pyodbc/#params).

Comment: @Bryan, Look at OP request, Writing for relative newbie, without rewriting entire SQL statement...

Comment: Thanks everyone for inputs..@PaulHarrington..your suggestion worked.

Comment: @vishalbhatt,  if the anser helped, please upvote,

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlquery = "select top 10000 * from Pretty_Txns where Pay_Date between :date1 and :date2"

df=pd.read_sql(sqlquery,cnx, params=dict(date1=date1, date2=date2))
```

If your driver does not support named placeholders then use question marks as before and pass in a list of [date1, date2] as the value to params.

Comment: It is essential for my code that I call the function in this manner
 func1(dt.date(2015,05,01),dt.date(2015,05,02)). So the proposed solution will not work.